# Visualise page loading

Tags: node.js, load, profiling

I often use page profiling with Google Chrome in order to measure the performance of my node.js app,

but I would like to save the result of profiling and make a benchmark and compare them.

I search on github but I can't find any project that could be a "dashboard" of page loading across time.

Any idea ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Try this: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk

Comment: Interesting ! This is a good start :) Thank you

Comment: You're welcome :). If this matches your needs tell me I'll put it as an answer

Comment: Well not exactly, because even if Batarang can export it's result, I can't use them in an external app for benchmark. I definitely think that I will have to develop my own app :)